# Why my mesh turns black?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new here.

My problem is.... my mesh turns black, I don't know why also when I create a new object like a cube it turns black as well, I recalculated the normals and nothing happened, please help me?

What can I do for solving my problem?

Thanks for your help

Screenshot 
[image: Black]

My file

[image]

Comment: You are in Texture Draw Mode, what happens when you you change it back to Solid draw mode? The icon next to the Object mode in the lower window header.....

Comment: Also, it's possible that you have a sun light object pointing directly downward, and you switched your shading mode to Material or Rendered.

Comment: The black mesh disappears, the problem happens only when I rendered the object or change the texture view...

Comment: @TeaCrab Thanks for the answer, I just started to create the model just extrude and inset the model to created a pyramid, and the mesh turns into black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the light is set in the correct direction.

[image]

Also, you are working in texture mode, switching to solid mode might be easier to work the model until you are ready to add a texture to it.[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I just started to use blender and I have much to learn! you help me a lot! I own you one

Comment: @Victor both please read the comments to your question. Both things were already pointed out by others!